# How can I check for function caller in Solana/rust like msg,sender in solidity?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana

I'm an eth dev who shifted to Solana for a project. I need to restrict the function call to a specific wallet. Is there any way to check who invoked the function call?

Answer (score 1):

So, the accounts that you are sending to the program function, as well as the signing account, are available at the program entry point as an array of `AccountInfo` structures. Each of which contains the public key for the account.

In your program you should store the 32 byte public key of the wallet you are restricting to in a program data area, so that when you are processing in your program you can check the account representing the signer and compare to your stored pub key.